# Como usar open cv com nodejs em ambiente de produção

Tags: node.js, git, opencv, npm, host

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em nodejs no qual utilizo o [opencv4nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs)
que permite usar a livraria opencv no nodeJS. A aplicação está pronta em servidor local, porém eu não idéia de como hospedar essa aplicação visto a dependência tem algumas particularidades. Eu tentei pela umbler (nodejs) porém como eu já imaginava não é possível mesmo sem a pasta node_modules no .gitignore.
Alguem por por favor consegue me ajudar a fazer isso funcionar em ambiente de produção?

Answer (score 1):

Como está seu package.json?
Geralmente plataformas como a Umbler fazem tudo automaticamente a partir do seu package.json... Dá uma olhadinha [aqui](https://help.umbler.com/hc/pt-br/articles/115001793863-Node-JS-na-Umbler)

Comment: Então, como eu disse a dependência tem algumas particularidades, se colocar ela no package.json vai dar erro porque no localhost por exemplo precisa do opencv instalado e configurar as variaveis de ambiente senão também da erro na hora do npm install.

Comment: Ah, sim! Entendi! O EC2 da AWS resolve seu problema...
É uma maquina dedicada, você pode subir ubuntu, acessar por SSH, instalar o OpenCV e fazer as demais configurações da sua aplicação. Lembrando que a AWS dispõe uma quota gratuita pra você fazer uns testes e configurar antes de "por pra rodar pra valer"

Comment: É possível continuar usando a umbler como o host da app em node?

Comment: @lalvesoliveira Favor elaborar melhor a resposta e ler [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/75104)